# Getting Error using Teechart for Mono for Android

Tags: teechart

I am getting error while compiling Demo project of TeeChart for Android (Beta version):

```
Error   1
The type 'Android.Widget.FrameLayout' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd'.
F:\Digital\Digital Mobile Development group\Projects\POC for CT\Supported Component\TeeChartMonodroidBeta201200515\TeeChartMonodroidBeta201200515\Examples\MonoAndroidDemo\ChartEditor.cs   21  20  MonoAndroidDemo
```

Please help

Thanks

---

I have verified & refrence to Mono.Android is proper.

Also, to mention that it is not working on my home machine. but on different machine it doesn't show any error while compiling & app get deployed to Android emulator successfully but when i run the app & select any chart option it shows blank screen & come again to list of chart types. Is this component applicable to specific Android version only?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check that your MonoAndroidDemo project has the Mono.Android.dll reference and if it's broken or missing try adding it again?

Comment: have verified & refrence to Mono.Android is proper.

Also, to mention that it is not working on my home machine. but on different machine it doesn't show any error while compiling & app get deployed to Android emulator successfully but when i run the app & select any chart option it shows blank screen & come again to list of chart types. Is this component applicable to specific Android version only?

Comment: @SanjayJha TeeChart Mono for Android is compiled for Android 2.2 and above. Which Android version are you using?

Comment: @SanjayJha It works fine for me here with an Android 2.2 emulator instance. Which are the settings of your emulator so that I can try it here? I'm creating emulator instances similar to what's explained at http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation/Installation_for_Windows